# Restrict to 2 decimal places in keypress of a text box?

Tags: javascript, validation, keypress

I want to enter a decimal point in a text box. I want to restrict the user by entering more than 2 digits after the decimal point. I have written the code for achieving that in the Keypress event.

```
function validateFloatKeyPress(el, evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;

    if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (charCode == 46 && el.value.indexOf(".") !== -1) {
        return false;
    }

    if (el.value.indexOf(".") !== -1)
    {
        var range = document.selection.createRange();

        if (range.text != ""){
        }
        else
        {
            var number = el.value.split('.');
            if (number.length == 2 && number[1].length > 1)
                return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTeamSizeCount" runat="server" onkeypress="return validateFloatKeyPress(this,event);" Width="100px" MaxLength="6"></asp:TextBox>
```

The code is working but the issue is: if I enter **".75"** and then change it to **"1.75"**, it is not possible. Only way to do it is delete it completely and then type **"1.75"**. This issue occurs if there are already 2 digits after decimal in the textbox. The conditions that I impose are

a) After decimal is present, it must at least have 1 or 2 digits. For ex **.75 or .7 or 10.75 or 333.55 or 333.2** is accepted. but not **.753 or 12.3335**

b) Before the decimal, it not a must for the user to enter a value. User must also be able to enter integer numbers also.

Can you tell me what could be the issue?

Thanks,
Jollyguy

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You were almost there. Just check that there are no more than 2 characters after the decimal.

UPDATE 1 - check carat position to allow character insertion before the decimal.
**UPDATE 2 - correct issue pointed out by ddlab's comment and only allow one dot.**

```
 function validateFloatKeyPress(el, evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
    var number = el.value.split('.');
    if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
    //just one dot (thanks ddlab)
    if(number.length>1 && charCode == 46){
         return false;
    }
    //get the carat position
    var caratPos = getSelectionStart(el);
    var dotPos = el.value.indexOf(".");
    if( caratPos > dotPos && dotPos>-1 && (number[1].length > 1)){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

//thanks: http://javascript.nwbox.com/cursor_position/
function getSelectionStart(o) {
    if (o.createTextRange) {
        var r = document.selection.createRange().duplicate()
        r.moveEnd('character', o.value.length)
        if (r.text == '') return o.value.length
        return o.value.lastIndexOf(r.text)
    } else return o.selectionStart
}
```

<strike>http://jsfiddle.net/S9G8C/1/</strike>
http://jsfiddle.net/S9G8C/203/

Comment: sorry for the delay, took a day off. your code is not working bcos it is not allowing to enter any nos before the decimal when there are 2 digits after decimal.

Comment: Sorry, but the jsfiddle example seems to miss a real input validation. I can enter 8.8.8.8.999 without any problem. Only if I enter a correct number value like 888.99 it works as expected. :-(

Comment: @ddlab - Doh! Thanks for pointing that out. I've updated my answer to correct for this.

Comment: @user2419435 as you can see from the example fiddle, the method is called by an onkeypress attribute in the input element itself  `onkeypress="return validateFloatKeyPress(this,event);"`. This isn't usually how I'd recommend you do this but my answer was a fix to existing code. [Here's an updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S9G8C/306/)

Comment: Its nice. Do you know something like when i press 1, it will automatically change to `01.00` something that will always convert number to 2 decimal places.

Comment: @Moob: I am able to type more than 2 characters after decimal dot in IE11 on Win10. Trying to find a solution...

Comment: Anyone can copy 2.22 and paste as many times as he/she wants. So this code should also take care of this.

Answer (score 12):

Consider leveraging HTML5's Constraint Validation API. It doesn't necessarily prevent typing invalid values, but the field is marked invalid and it halts submission of the `<form>` (by default). I added the `<output>` to illustrate why the browser considers e.g. "1.100" a valid value (it sees the numeric value as "1.1").

```html
<input id="n" type="number" step=".01">
```

```js
var
  n = document.getElementById('n'),
  o = document.getElementById('o'),
  didInputN = function(e) {
    o.value = n.valueAsNumber;
  };

n.addEventListener('input', didInputN);
```

```css
input:invalid {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input id="n" type="number" step=".01">
<output id="o" for="n"></output>
```

Philosophically, you might consider this a more usable approach as it allows the user to paste an invalid entry and edit it directly in the field.

Comment: Nice. This is much better than fixing the OP's script as I did. Kudos.

Answer (score 9):

You can do it by another way with onchange event, to not restrict to user to type, rather just convert number after typing, to make uniform, like this,

```js
function validateFloatKeyPress(el) {
    var v = parseFloat(el.value);
    el.value = (isNaN(v)) ? '' : v.toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<input id="aninput" type="text" onchange="validateFloatKeyPress(this);" />
```

`45.846` should be `45.85` but in your code user needed to convert their-self and then they will type `45.85` directly

Answer (score 4):

```
1.)No multiple decimals points.
2.)Two numbers after decimal point.
3.)Allow only Numbers and one decimal point(.).
```

This will help.[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Surendra0108/s4ywLapp/2/)

Comment: After typing in a number with 2 decimal value your code allow to edit that number

Answer (score 1):

```
 function decimalValidation(el, evt) {
       var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
       var number = el.value.split('.');
         if(charCode == 8) {
          return true;
         }
        if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
            return false;
        }
        //just one dot
        if(number.length>1 && charCode == 46){
             return false;
        }
        //get the carat position
        var caratPos = getSelectionStart(el);
        var dotPos = el.value.indexOf(".");
        if( caratPos > dotPos && dotPos>-1 && (number[1].length > 1)){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

function getSelectionStart(o) {
    return o.selectionStart
}
```

Hi @webvitaly The above code will work in IE too please check
And backspace after decimals not working in Mozilla i updated my answer.

Comment: is there a way to include typing decimal point before typing number i.e type .5 (which validates to 0.5 OnBlur). Your current solution wont allow me to type decimal point if I haven't typed in a value yet.

Answer (score 0):

this code is very complet, I change "." to ",":

- can't "," in begin
- can't write more ","

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript">

      function isNumberKey(evt, el) {
          var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
          var number = el.value.split(',');
          var caracter = el.value;

          if (charCode != 44 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
              return false;
          }

          if (charCode == 44 && caracter == "") {
              return false;
          }

          if (charCode == 44 && caracter.indexOf(",") != -1) {
              return false;
          }

          //get the carat position
          var caratPos = getSelectionStart(el);
          var dotPos = el.value.indexOf(",");
          if (caratPos > dotPos && dotPos > -1 && (number[1].length > 1)) {
              return false;
          }
          return true;
      }

      function getSelectionStart(o) {
          if (o.createTextRange) {
              var r = document.selection.createRange().duplicate()
              r.moveEnd('character', o.value.length)
              if (r.text == '') return o.value.length
              return o.value.lastIndexOf(r.text)
          } else return o.selectionStart
      }

  </script>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I need it to show an error message in real time if the user is allowed only 2 decimals:

```
value = parseFloat(valueFromInput);
parseFloat(value.toFixed(2)) !== value // condition to check
```

The above code worked for me.`.toFixed` converts the float to a string wit only 2 decimals and I have to convert back to float to check with the initial value if are the same.

P.S. And before this condition you should check if the value is NaN.