# Javascript validator for input text field for two decimals only

Tags: javascript

How would one validate and restrict input text field for two decimals only, without using JQuery or this syntax:

```
  RegExpObject.test(string)
```

Comment: Why you don't want a regex?

Comment: Is this a question or a challenge?

Comment: @isvforall I had an interview yesterday with cisco and they asked me this question. BTW, I asked them back the same question you just asked me. Thanks,

Comment: @SterlingArcher its a question. Please if you can help me out how to solve it, would be much appreciated. Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plain JavaScript, without regex:

```
var str = '12.34'

var n = Number(str.split('.')[1]);

if (n > 9 && n < 100) console.log("It's good");
```

Comment: I meant by two decimals is two decimals after the dot. for example:- xx.22 is good, x.234 is not good. Thanks,

Comment: Perfect solution. Thank you so much. But why my reputation got decreased by 4 points?

Comment: @OmarAlQuaseer someone downvoted your question

Answer (score 0):

Even possible in plain HTML5 if you dont want JavaScript.

```
<input type="number" name="quantity" step="2" min="0" max="99">
```

For plain simple javascript, use benefit of this

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp

How to apply ? See Rishi's Answer from

[restrict to 2 decimal places in keypress of a text box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23221557/restrict-to-2-decimal-places-in-keypress-of-a-text-box)

Comment: No, I want it in a javascript as I mentioned above. Thank you though.