# How can limit to 2 decimals in TextBoxFor in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.textboxfor

I want after decimal point only 2 digit.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Viewers, new { @tabindex = 7 })
```

Need output like this:

56.23

456.20

1.21

like that..

Comment: is a Jquery solution acceptable?

Comment: Did you tried string.Format?

Comment: @Reddy .Ya of course. it is.

Comment: @AbhilashJA see if this thread helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23221557/restrict-to-2-decimal-places-in-keypress-of-a-text-box

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use editor templates in my views. I would define view models which are specifically tailored to the requirements of the given view (in this case limiting it to 2 decimals):

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public decimal Viewers{ get; set; }
```

or You can simply use regular expression with model like

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\d+.\d{0,2}$")]
public decimal Viewers{ get; set; }
```

and then in html:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Viewers)
```

or `TextBoxFor()`will also work with regular expression

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Viewers, new { @tabindex = 7 })
```

Answer (score 2):

In View

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Viewers, new { @tabindex = 7 }, new { Value=String.Format("{0:0.##}",Model.Viewers) })
```

In controller also you can format your String.Format("{0:0.##}",Object.viewers)

Object- Means model(contains field Viewers) which is passed to View

Hope this is helpful

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to format your decimals on client side like this:

In your `ViewModel`:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public decimal Viewers { get; set; }
```

And on your View use `EditorFor`:

```
 @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Viewers, new { @tabindex = 7 })
```

When this value posts to your `Controller` just trim it to 2 nums.

If you need validation use Regex:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\d+\.\d{0,2}$")] //this line
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public decimal Viewers { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I use.

```
String.Format("{0:0.00}", 123.4567);
```

So result:

```
 // "123.46"
```

So you can try this

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => String.Format("{0:0.00}", m.Viewers) , new { @tabindex = 7 })
```

Comment: "HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable." - got error like this.

Comment: try rebuild this is not Html code error please check help for this error here. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/942041

Answer (score 0):

```js
  $("#Viewers").change(function (e) {

            var num = parseFloat($(this).val());
            $(this).val(num.toFixed(2));
});
```

```html
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Viewers, new { @tabindex = 7 })
```

Thank you for all to reply me !!! :)