# Identify edit before decimal using keydown event

Tags: javascript, angular6, keydown

I have requirement to validate input before it appears using angular 6. Requirement is to identify whether I'm editing before decimal or after. If it before decimal i have to allow and if not then i have to restrict. 
Ex. 138.02
( If i'm typing before decimal like 4 after 138 then it should work and new value should be 1384.02 but if i type after .02 ( any digit) It should not work.

I am following below code

```
function validateFloatKeyPress(el, evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
    var number = el.value.split('.');
    if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
    //just one dot (thanks ddlab)
    if(number.length>1 && charCode == 46){
         return false;
    }
    //get the carat position
    var caratPos = getSelectionStart(el);
    var dotPos = el.value.indexOf(".");
    if( caratPos > dotPos && dotPos>-1 && (number[1].length > 1)){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

//thanks: http://javascript.nwbox.com/cursor_position/
function getSelectionStart(o) {
    if (o.createTextRange) {
        var r = document.selection.createRange().duplicate()
        r.moveEnd('character', o.value.length)
        if (r.text == '') return o.value.length
        return o.value.lastIndexOf(r.text)
    } else return o.selectionStart
}
```

document.selection.createRange().duplicate() is not working with Angular 6?

Comment: Sounds great. What have you already tried and why didn't it work?

Comment: I have the similar issue mentioned here ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23221557/restrict-to-2-decimal-places-in-keypress-of-a-text-box ). The given solution is not working for me.

Comment: what i'm trying is to get the cursor position as i typed and can compare with decimal index. If it less then i can allow to add value.

Comment: Since you use Angular, can’t you use `ngOnChanges` to  listen for changes in the variable that is bound to the text field? If the decimal value changed, then you reset the variable to the previous value. That way you won’t need to access the DOM or read the caret position.

Comment: Hi Kokodoko, Can you add some example for this?